# Collision between physics object and non physics object in physics room game maker 2

Tags: game-physics, collision, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I have trouble for getting collision in my game.

I have a physics room and some object. I have two objects where `uses physics` is active.
I make them collide. and it's still ok.

But when I try to add some object without `uses physics` in my room physics,
the two object before can't collide again.

If I remove the object without `uses physics`, the two object before can collide again.

How to solve the 2 objects with `uses physics` before. in order to be able collide as before, even though I add objects with non physics in my physics room.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to detect a collision between a physics object and a non-physics object. However, what you could do is *simulate* a physics object to act like a non-physics object.

Enable `use physics` for the non-physics object but manipulate it using the non-physics properties (e.g. vspeed, gravity, etc). Make it a Sensor so that it will trigger a collision without causing the other object to rebound. In the Step/End Step Event of the object, add the following GML code which will update the physics properties of the object based on any changes to the non-physics properties:

```
phy_fixed_rotation = true;
vspeed += gravity;
vspeed -= sign( vspeed ) * min( abs( vspeed ), friction );
hspeed -= sign( hspeed ) * min( abs( hspeed ), friction );
phy_speed_x = hspeed;
phy_speed_y = vspeed;
phy_position_x = x;
phy_position_y = y;
phy_rotation = -image_angle;
```

Now you should be able to move the object using non-physics properties, and hence collisions should be detected.